# Gitflow with two streams of work

Tags: git, branch, release, release-management, git-flow

We're currently using Gitflow in a very standard way to support weekly sprints.

In a bid to ease pressure, we're about to move to a slightly different release schedule which will involve weekly 'small change' sprints, and bi-weekly 'functional change' sprints, all within the same website/git repo.

To do this, I need to find a way of being able to finish features for the bi-weekly functional change sprint, without them being included within the weekly small change sprint release.

Is there a way to have two develop branches... a 'small change' develop branch, and a 'functional change' develop branch, and then features are created in each respective branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking just about the GitFlow branching model, or the git extensions that some teams use to automate the branch/merge tasks called for by that model?

If you're just using the branching model, then of course you can vary it in whatever way suits your team.  I can think of several ways to accomplish what you describe, though they each have potential drawbacks; you'd just have to decide what works for your team.

If you're using git extensions, then I can't think of any way to make them directly support what you want; so the key would be to modify the branching workflow in a way that preserves as much of the extensions' functionality as possible.  (Or, the tools are open source... I suppose you could modify them.  Or just set the extensions aside; I've never really understood them to provide that much value, tough of course I could be missing something.)

Generally you should be wary of adding new long-lived branches to the model, because it provides the opportunity for things to fall out of sync.  In your case, you can sync up every one or two weeks at worst.  I suppose in theory the "small change" branch shouldn't do anything so sweeping that it's likely to create a difficult merge conflict... but then, do you know the difference between theory and practice? [1]

I would be inclined to keep things looking as "normal" as possible from the `master` branch's point of view.  That would mean that `develop` should be the source of all release branches and everything on `develop` should be ready for the next release; which in turn means that `develop` is the direct branch and merge point for "small change" features.

Then you could just treat each "functional change" sprint as a feature itself.  So at the beginning of "functional change sprint N" you would create, from `develop`, a branch - let's say `fchangeN`.  The features for the functional change sprint would be branched from, and merged back to, `fchangeN`, and at the end of two weeks `fchangeN` would be merged to `develop` (and presumably deleted).

A question you'd have to ask: if a hotfix is applied and merged to `master` and `develop`, should it also be merged to the active `fchangeN` branch?  Normally you wouldn't think of merging a hotfix directly to a feature branch, which is more or less how we're trying to treat `fchangeN`; but it really is a bigger accumulation of changes, so it might be worth thinking about whether a hotfix is likely to impact those two weeks' worth of code.

I guess you could similarly ask yourself whether you should merge small-change features into `fchangeN` - or, if not that, maybe merge `develop` into `fchangeN` at the mid-sprint point (where you're switching from one small-change sprint to the next).  I would hope that small changes, being *small*, wouldn't be that important to the sprint effort; but again, your team would have to decide if it's worth the extra work for your team.

A variation of the above: you might notice that you delete `fchangeN` just as you create `fchange(N+1)`; so you could just keep a single branch `fchange`.  The trick then is to make sure to merge "both ways" with `develop` after every two weeks.

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff fchange
git checkout fchange
git checkout --ff-only develop
```

With either variation, a more interesting question is: what do you do with "functional change" features that aren't done at end of sprint?  In theory you can just keep the feature branch open/unmerged.  As the story carries over into the subsequent sprint, the feature branch would merge back into the subsequent sprint's `fchangeN` branch.

Is this "the" way to do it?  No.  There isn't any one way, as what you're doing is trying to customize the workflow to meet a custom requirement.  It's a way, which may have some drawbacks and may or may not be right for your team.  Its goal is to keep things as "normal" as possible, preferring that "odd" behavior should be on the most transient branches and the most permanent branches should act normally.

---

[1] - The difference between theory and practice is: in theory there is no difference